# ZF2: ZfcUser redirect after login with Ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework2

I use ZfcUser in my Project. I have now got a link to be able to Bookmark an Advert. I use jQuery Ajax for this to jump into the Action of my Controller. To be able to set a Bookmark, I have to be logged in. If a User is not logged in, a re-direct to the Log-in Page happens.

This all works very well now, but I was wondering if it's possible to redirect to my Advert Page, after the User logs in, best would even be that the Bookmark gets automatically set, since this was the last the User tried to achieve. Right now I get redirected to the Page which is defined in the 
zfcuser.global.php ('login_redirect_route'). And yes, I have set

```
'use_redirect_parameter_if_present' => true,
```

to true in the zfcuser.global.php file. but how would I use this now? I suppose it could be a problem because it goes through the Ajax Request and my re-direct is then achieved through

```
window.location.replace(response.redirect);
```

Is there any way to achieve this or do I expect too much?

```
 $(document).on("click", "#add-bookmark-link",function () {
            $.ajax({    
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { id: <?php echo $advertId;?>},
        url: '/add-bookmark',
        success: function(response) {
                    if (response.status == false)
                    {
                        window.location.replace(response.redirect);
                    }
                    else{
                        $('.add-bookmark').replaceWith('<p class="text-right remove-bookmark"><span class="danger glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign text-danger"></span> <a href="#" id="remove-bookmark-link">Remove Bookmark</a>');
                    }
            }
        });
    });
```

});

**AdvertController.php**

```
 public function addBookmarkAction() {    
    $advertId =  $this->params()->fromQuery('id',null);
    if ($this->zfcUserAuthentication()->hasIdentity()) {
        $this->getServiceLocator()->get('BookmarkAdvertService')->saveAdvertBookmark($advertId);
        $result = new JsonModel(array(  
                'status' =>true,
        ));
    }
    else{
        $result = new JsonModel(array(
                'status'   => false,
                'redirect' => $this->url()->fromRoute('zfcuser/login')
               ));
    }
    return $result;
}
```

**UPDATE**

After receiving below answer, I have updated my Sourcecode. Not sure I have done it right. It now goes straight to the below URL without showing the Login. The URL is also wrong, since it shows me [object Object]. Why is it now going to the Log-in?

```
http://mywebsite.com/ad/thenameoftheadvert/[object Object]
```

In general my URL should look like this in the end

```
http://mywebsite.com/ad/thenameoftheadvert/articleId.htm
```

What have I done wrong? I suppose I implemented the solution wrong...

```
public function addBookmarkAction() {    
    $advertId =  $this->params()->fromQuery('id',null);
    if ($this->zfcUserAuthentication()->hasIdentity()) {
            $this->getServiceLocator()->get('BookmarkAdvertService')->saveAdvertBookmark($advertId);
        $result = new JsonModel(array(  
                'status' =>true,
        ));
    }
    else{
        $name    = '/add-bookmark';
        $params  = array('advertId' => $advertId);
        $options = array();

        $bookmarkRedirect = $this->url($name, $params, $options);

        $name    = 'zfcuser/login';
        $params  = array(); 
        $options = array(
            'query' => array(
                'redirect' => $bookmarkRedirect
            ), 
        );   

        $loginRedirect = $this->url($name, $params, $options);
        $result = new JsonModel(array(
                'status'   => false,
                'redirect' => $loginRedirect
               ));
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you have to pass the redirect parameter as a query param and then it is rendered in the url like this:

```
http://www.example.com/login?redirect=http://www.example.com/object/1/add/bookmark
```

You can achieve this as follows.

First create a redirect for adding the bookmark:

```
$name    = 'add/bookmark';
$params  = array('object_id' => $object_id);
$options = array();

$bookmarkRedirect = $this->url($name, $params, $options);
```

Now create a redirect for login and add the redirect to the bookmark as a query param:

```
$name    = 'zfcuser/login';
$params  = array(); 
$options = array(
    'query' => array(
        'redirect' => $addBookmark
    ), 
);   

$loginRedirect = $this->url($name, $params, $options);
```

Return this in your JsonModel:

```
$result = new JsonModel(array(
    'status'   => false,
    'redirect' => $loginRedirect
));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!! I have updated my Post with your solution, unfortunately it does not work yet. What have I done wrong? Did I misunderstand your answer?